# Adding Shadows to MKMapView

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, shadow

I've a MapView, and I want to add it a dropshadow, but the method I tried doesn't work:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    mapView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]; 
    mapView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10.0f, 10.0f);
    mapView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
    mapView.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
}
```

I get this:

[image: example]

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Resolved thanks to: http://blog.amarkulo.com/create-rounded-uiviews-with-shadow

using this code:

```
[[mapView layer] setMasksToBounds:NO];
[[mapView layer] setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
[[mapView layer] setShadowOpacity:1.0f];
[[mapView layer] setShadowRadius:6.0f];
[[mapView layer] setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 3)];
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative (actually the proposed solution didn't work for me, iOS SDK 4.3) is to enclose the MKMapView in a UIView:

```
_mapContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake (0.0f, 44.0f, 320.0f, container.frame.size.height - 44.0f)];
_mapContainer.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
_mapContainer.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
_mapContainer.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
_mapContainer.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake (0.0f, 10.0f);
_mapContainer.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6f;
_mapContainer.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0f;
[container addSubview: _mapContainer];
[_mapContainer release];

_mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame: _mapContainer.bounds];
_mapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[_mapContainer addSubview: _mapView];
[_mapView release];
```

This way you can also animate the frame of the _mapContainer and still keep the shadow in its correct place.

Here you can see actual results [here](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/120261), if you're a registered Apple developer.